# Is head voice usable in comfortable range?

Tags: vocal-range, voice-training, voice-change

So im a baritone with d2 to c5 or d5(not sure yet because im still struggling in high notes). In one of my recent classes i might have realized something but not sure yet. I used to use my head voice after e4/f4 and fail to hit a4 let alone b4 but when i tried to sing from g4 to c5 without head voice it was more stable. At that point i also start to feel how head voice feels in my body and realised i might have used head voice in lower notes accidently and didnt realize back then; judging by how those notes sound and felt in my body.
My question is; is head voice there to go past your comfortable zone or it can be used in your comfortable zone? What exactly is head voice for?

Comment: What is is that you consider *head voice*?

Comment: You mention classes. What did your teacher say when they were asked?

Comment: I’m asking to make sure we think of the same terms when talking about head voice. Do you mean the type of head voice where only the vocal cords vibrate, or do you mean falsetto?

Comment: @Lazy's question about what you consider head voice... I am agreeing with that. Are you belting when you go above B4? Belting basically means getting loud. Anyway, your question is more about bringing head voice down, and the answer is yes. I am baritone E2->F5. At about F4, I break; I need to mix or go into head voice, or get loud. I can bring my head voice down to F3 and it still sound good. It's a fun effect to sing, say, a really comfy A3 in chest, and then again in head. So "what exactly is head voice for"... I would argue it's: to create different types of sounds throughout your range.